# Sales figures not displayed in form

Tags: vb.net

Trying to calculate total sales for 5 items, 3 stores.
Here's a s/s of what Im getting, along with my code.
What am I missing/doing wrong?
(p.s. It's not returning an error code in 'debug')
[image]

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        Dim ttlsales As Double
        'set up array data

        Dim sales(,) As Integer = {{25, 64, 23, 45, 14},
                                  {12, 82, 19, 34, 63},
                                   {54, 22, 17, 43, 35}}
        Dim price() As Double = {12.0, 17.95, 95.0, 86.5, 78.0}

        'mark totals
        Dim totals(2) As Double
        For store As Integer = 0 To 2
            For item As Integer = 0 To 4
            Next
        Next

        'display output
        lstOut.Items.Add("Sales Per Store")
        For store As Integer = 0 To 2
            lstOut.Items.Add(store + 1 & ":" &
                             FormatCurrency(totals(store)))
            ttlsales += totals(store)
        Next

        lstOut.Items.Add("Total Sales: " &
                         FormatCurrency(ttlsales))


    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, you are not doing anything in your double for loop

```
Dim totals(2) As Double
For store As Integer = 0 To 2
            For item As Integer = 0 To 4
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: That was it!   Thanks, I rechecked the code, added a line to ttl it all, and it works -thank you.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you forgot to stick something in here. it does nothing

```
 For store As Integer = 0 To 2
      For item As Integer = 0 To 4
      Next
 Next
```

Comment: it could be polite to accept both answers since they are the both the same. no biggie.

Comment: clicked the up arrow for you, think that was it